# How does the Michael shutdown exploitation (TKIP) work?

Tags: encryption, network, wifi, attacks, wpa2

How exactly does the [Michael shutdown exploitation (TKIP)](http://kalilinuxtutorials.com/mdk3/) work?

I know that cancels all traffic continuously, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDK3's [GitHub page](https://github.com/wi-fi-analyzer/mdk3-master/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=michael&type=), it uses a "TKIP QoS Exploit".

This is the [note](https://github.com/wi-fi-analyzer/mdk3-master/blob/1bf2bd31b79560aa99fc42123f70f36a03154b9e/CHANGELOG) from the code:

> can shut down APs using TKIP encryption and QoS Extension with 1
>   sniffed and 2 injected QoS Data Packets.

Looking up the specific exploit, you will run across [this paper](http://securedsolutions.com.my/pdf/WhitePapers/TKIPExploit.pdf) (one of many) that explains it:

> TKIP was introduced in 2003, and amongst other enhancements, included
>   a new per packet hashing algorithm, the Message Integrity Check (MIC).
>   MIC is based on a weak algorithm, designed to be accommodated on
>   legacy WEP hardware. TKIP uses MIC for guaranteeing the integrity of
>   an encrypted frame. If more than two MIC failures are observed in a 60
>   second window, both the Access Point (AP) and client station shut down
>   for 60 seconds.

When you have a question about how an open source tool does something, take a look at the code. Even if you are not a programmer, you will often find the details you need in the documentation, comments, or in this case, the CHANGELOG.